# Synthesizing crowd-sourced data to get a consensus estimate

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, modeling

I have some data of different people's estimates for the value of a numerical variable for a bunch of different objects, and I want to get a consensus estimate of the value of the variable for each object. So, my data is a bunch of rows that look like: (user, object, estimate). Ideally, I would like to use a model that generates estimates of the users' trustworthiness (probably based on how well they agree with the other users) and then uses these trustworthiness scores to generate estimates of the variable's values for each object. I also need a confidence interval for the final estimates. Does anyone know how I could do this, or at least know where I could look for something like this?

Extra complications: In my application, this data will be flowing in a real-time, and I will need to produce estimates of variable values with confidence intervals on the spot. Also, users will be generating estimates about several different variables, and it would be nice if the user trustworthiness estimates for each variable could update based on the trustworthiness estimates for the other variables. Any insights on these aspects would be appreciated as well.

Comment: How many people? I also think to remember that the simple mean is often a very good predictor.